Wittgenstein vs Nietzsche in a debate about the existence of absolute truth
Connected to this question of mine about the absolute truth paradox.
I read on the net a debate between two people about the existence of absolute truth.
One of the possible conclusions that most intrigued me was this one:

"The statement: "The absolute truth: "There are no absolute
truths."  is only paradoxical if we accept the axioms of classical
logic."
"But why should we assume Axioms of classical logic?
Why not other type of logic?
Why should we even assume any system of reasoning? For reasoning to
exist?
What is the reason for reason to exist?"

The person that gave that answer was than recommended to read Wittgenstein and his Tractatus .
Than, the discussion continued and another person said that Tractatus is "bad" (he said a harsher word, which I do now want to repeat) and that Wittgenstein even wrote Philosophical Investigations to counter his own older opinions.
Than it is also commented that "Anyone familiar with Nietzsche should be able to recognise that book (Tractatus) is unworthy." (again I am paraphrasing to avoid harsh words).
Would you recommend that I read Tractatus?
What works would you recommend that most closely follow the path of the quoted excerpt I provided and in what way was Nietzsche superior to Wittgenstein in the context of the possible resolution of what (and if it exists) absolute truth is?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Hm, sorry, maybe I made a mistake. I did not read Tractatus. I just came to that conclusion from reading that discussion that both philosophers were discussing the same "truth".

The "Tractatus" is worth reading, but only if you follow up by reading the "Philosophical Investigations".
But to get at your real question here, let's look at the philosophical trajectory. Wittgenstein wrote the Tractatus when he was working in the orbit of Russell's analytic philosophy. Russell's analytic philosophy was working on the assumption that philosophy could be studied using the same model as the physical sciences: that we could reduce philosophical question to clear logical/empirical statements. Now, this approach — while brilliant enough — ran into some distinct problems concerning language and reference. For one, it relied on strict denotation: elements of logical statements needed clear and unambiguous references to 'objects' in the world. Conventional language clearly doesn't follow this rule — some objects have multiple terms that reference them, and some terms reference different objects depending on context — and trying to rationalize conventional language into a purer philosophical language turned out to be an intractable problem. Russell's paradigm had difficulty with negational self-reference (see Russell's Paradox). The Tractatus was Wittgenstein's effort to patch up the problems in Russell's paradigm, through a few innovative tricks:

He distinguished between the world itself and the world of 'facts', where the latter consists of those analytic statements we can make about the world
He dismissed non-analytic statements as 'non-facts' that carry no meaning
He converted self-reference into a kind of meta-reference, so that the thing being referred to is always different from the thing referring, even when they appear to be the same.

So here we can start to see the problem Wittgenstein is working on. Intuitively, we want to think that 'facts' are part of the objective world, existing independently of observation or conscious activity. But Wittgenstein is suggesting that 'facts' are not part of the objective world, but are (instead) elements of a properly constituted philosophical language. He's still carrying the presumption that these linguistic 'facts' strictly denote elements of the objective world, but he has subtly pulled facticity out of empiricism and into a form of psychologism.
In the Philosophical Investigations Wittgenstein carries this idea towards its logical end. He still holds that there's an 'objective' world where 'stuff' exists, but now he separates language from strict denotation. Language is entirely by convention, based in the use of words in social interaction. worse yet, human communication carries multitudes of conventions, and we need to track which convention we're in. He calls these language games, in analogy to actual games. In a game like chess we need to know certain basic rules about what the pieces are and how they move — rules that are nothing more than arbitrary conventions — and then we can have a chess 'conversation' by moving the pieces according to the rules. So then we have to think: are we doing 'science', or 'philosophy' or 'poetry'? All of these are different language games with different rules and conventions, and by playing those games properly we find different kinds of 'truths'.
In this sense, Wittgenstein is moving away from Analytic Philosophy's empiricism towards Continental philosophy's rationalism. He never fully gets there (nor should he, necessarily) but that does explain why Nietzsche and later European philosophers would not respect the Tractatus, which is sill quite empiricist.

The Wittgenstein that wrote the Tractatus is known as the early Wittgenstein. This work is based on logic and very ambitious: it seeks to solve philosophy and Wittgenstein claimed that he had succeeded in doing so. Others would say that he not so much solved philosophy, as dissolved philosophy by simply excluding everything metaphysical... It states that truth is the correspondence between facts and reality. Famously: The world is all that is the case. The book is peculiar in style and simply consists of propositions and statements without much argumentation. Wittgenstein thought them self evident.
Whereas the early Wittgenstein was a proponent of Analytic Philosophy, Nietzsche can be seen as a precursor of Continental Philosophy. I can't think of a lot of overlap between these two thinkers. Nietzsche would more agree with the absence of absolute truth and the idea that truth depends on perspective and that it is a human construct. Wittgenstein wrote: Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must be silent", but Nietzsche just wouldn't shut up...
Should you read the Tractatus? Hard to say. It is not easy and some people would say it is not relevant because the later Wittgenstein rejected a lot of his earlier work. But it is still a book of beauty and austerity. It is not very long and you'll get an idea if you read the seven main propositions.
Now I think of it, if there's anything that Nietzsche and Wittgenstein had in common, it is the fact that they were both great writers. Especially if you read German.

If you can read Badiou's Seminars on "antiphilosophy" you would see Nietzsche and Wittgensteim almost as twins; it's fascinating...

Not an answer, but only a comment from the point of view of someone thinking that philosophy is not a science but we stiil have to try to base it on "facts". Thus, interpretations of philosophers must firstly and foremost be based on texts.
Compare Wittgenstein's Tractatus (1921):

2.222 The agreement or disagreement of its sense with reality
constitutes its truth or falsity.

And:

4.464 A tautology’s truth is certain, a proposition’s possible, a contradiction’s impossible.

With some more Nietzsce's quotes: "tuth is the kind of error without which a certain kind of being could not live", and "there are no facts, only interpretations".
Relevant: Richard Rorty's collection Objectivity Relativism and Truth (1991).
Regarding so-called second Wittgenstein, there are very few occurrences of "truth" in Philosophical Investigations (1953).
More relevant the posthumous On Certainty (1952/1969). See e.g. Annalisa Coliva, Was Wittgenstein an Epistemic Relativist? (Phil.Inv., 2010).

Re. 2.222 "The agreement or disagreement of its sense with reality" would establish a perspective 'truth' as the agreement of assertion (notion or sense) with (sensory) 'sense'(!) data (aka reality). This is fine with Nietzsche : "facts are precisely what is lacking, all that exists consists of interpretations." WtP 481. Nietzsche is saying there is no absolute truth, but the judged truth of an assertion confirmed by sense data evidence is a perspective 'truth' that he would accept, given that sense data can be deceptive.

So I feel your Wittgenstein and Nietzsche quotes are saying the same thing. (I think you might have meant them to contrast. Certainly they differ in expression, but as I read them they agree.)

Hi, would you recommend reading Philosophical Investigations first or On Certainty first?
